# How can I make trailing spaces visible within rotated text in Excel?

Tags: excel

I'm creating a spreadsheet which contains text that's rotated at 90 degrees within some of the cells, which form part of a diagram. The diagram is symmetrical, where the cells at the top of the diagram are aligned to the bottom (thus the text is effectively left-aligned), and the cells at the bottom of the diagram are aligned to the top (thus the text is right-aligned).

In order to make the diagram clearer, I have inserted leading spaces to the cells at the top of the diagram, and trailing spaces to the cells at the bottom of the diagram. I've set the cell formats to text to ensure that numbers are treated as such. However, the trailing spaces aren't appearing within the bottom cells for some reason (although they are present within the values as they appear within the formula bar). The values within the cells with the leading spaces are successfully being indented.

Please can someone point me to a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a workaround that does the job. Instead of adding a trailing "space", I use character U+00A0; this successfully indents the rotated, right-aligned text. I'm still wondering why it doesn't do it with a normal space though?